# Most efficient way to copy elements from a vector to another, given a list of indices which are not to be copied

Tags: c++, arrays, list, vector, stl

Let's say i have a vector `V = {5, 10, 2, 1, 6}` and a `list of indices= {2, 3, 0}`. Now the resulting data structure `U` should contain the elements `{10, 6}` not necessarily in order. The naive approach will have a time complexity of `O(n^2)`. Can we better that?

Comment: Presort `list` and then keep an iterator into `list` which is updated to point to the next element to skip.

Comment: how does the resulting data contain the elements {10, 6}??

Comment: @Null Because from the vector V, the elements V[2], V[3] and V[0] aren't copied in the new vector.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

you can add a bool array of the vector size to indicate whether this index will be taken or not, filling this array in O(n) and then you can loop over the vector and select the elements in another O(n) that will be O(2*n) = O(n), like the following:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <string.h>
using namespace std;

int main (){
    vector<int> items ;
    vector<int> notIncluded ;
    items.push_back(1);
    items.push_back(2);
    items.push_back(3);
    items.push_back(5);
    notIncluded.push_back(1);
    notIncluded.push_back(0);

    vector<int> selectedItems;

    bool idx[items.size()];
    memset(idx, true, sizeof(idx));

    for(int i=0;i<notIncluded.size();i++){
        idx[notIncluded[i]] = false;
    }

    for(int i=0;i<items.size();i++){
        if(idx[i]){
            selectedItems.push_back(items[i]);
            cout << items[i] << " " ;
        }
    }

return 0;
}
```

Comment: Similar to [Counting_sort](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Counting_sort).

Answer (score 0):

We can do in O(n*log(n)) by sorting the list of indices then selecting the elements from vector whose indices are not in the sorted list.
Sorting will take O(n*log(n)) and going through vector would be O(n)

> O(n*log(n))+O(n)=O(n*log(n))